# Icon images across multiple categories

Tags: categories, images

I have several blog posts which are cross tagged among categories (Economics, Politics, Environment etc.).

I have set featured images for each category on my home page display, rather than individual images for each post.

I'm using the FPW Category Thumbnails plugin. On my home page I have a tabbed widget which displays the posts sorted by categories, but the icons don't change to reflect the category they are sorting by.

Instead the first tagged category icon displays, no matter which tab I'm on. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Best practice is to only assign 1 category per post. If you want to continue assigning multiple categories, could you please share your homepage widget code?

Comment: Between using the plugin functionality and what sounds like custom widget it is quite impossible to guess how to adjust it. If someone did custom development work on this for the site they are probably the best to ask about working with it.

Comment: I should be able to help if you edit your question and add your widget code.